# Spring Integration Aggregator Continuing to output channel without release-strategy-expression being True

Tags: multithreading, spring-integration

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74146030/multithreading-in-spring-integration-sending-to-different-channels/74157075#74157075) a bit ago about a specific use case when multi-threading in spring integration, basically I have to have one thread of execution that stays on the initial and then a second that spawns a thread. I have implemented this like so

```xml
   <int:channel id="newThread" >
      <int:dispatcher task-executor="workerThreadPoolAdapter"/>
   </int:channel>

   <!--This bean is used to split incoming messages -->
   <bean id="splitterBean" class="orchestration.MessageSplitter">
      <property name="channels" ref="splitterChannelsList" />
   </bean>

   <util:list id="splitterChannelsList" value-type="java.lang.String">
      <value>newThread</value>
      <value>mainThread</value>
   </util:list>

   <!-- This bean is used to aggregate incoming messages -->
   <bean id="aggregator" class="orchestration.MessageAggregator">
      <property name="wrapperNode" value="container" />
   </bean>

   <!-- Channel for aggregator output and that will be input for response transformer -->
   <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="gatherChannel" apply-sequence="true"/>

   <!-- This splitter splits request and send -->
   <!-- will add a header called channelHeader which is the channel the message should be routed to using the recipient-list-router -->
   <int:splitter input-channel="splitter"
                 output-channel="recipientListRouter"
                 apply-sequence="true"
                 ref="splitterBean" method="split" />

   <!-- Aggregator that aggregates responses received from the calls -->
   <int:aggregator input-channel="gatherChannel"
                   output-channel="transformResponse"
                   ref="aggregator"
                   method="aggregateMessages"
                   send-partial-result-on-expiry="false"
                   expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
                   message-store="removeMessageFromStore"
                   release-strategy-expression="size() == 2"/>

   <int:recipient-list-router input-channel="recipientListRouter">
      <int:recipient channel="mainThread"
                     selector-expression="headers.get('channelHeader') == 'mainThread'"/>
      <int:recipient channel="newThread"
                     selector-expression="headers.get('channelHeader') == 'newThread'"/>
   </int:recipient-list-router>

   <!-- only route to call if boolean is populated -->
   <int:header-value-router header-name="shouldMakeExtraOutboundCall"
                            input-channel="newThread"
                            default-output-channel="gatherChannel" >
      <int:mapping value="true" channel="outboundCall" />
   </int:header-value-router>

   <int:chain input-channel="outboundCall" output-channel="gatherChannel">
       <!-- make an outbound call -->
   </int:chain>

   <int:chain input-channel="mainThread" output-channel="gatherChannel">
       <!-- make a bunch of outbound calls -->
   </int:chain>

   <int:chain input-channel="transformResponse" output-channel="backToClient">
       <!-- do some stuff and respond back to client -->
   </int:chain>
```

I've had the output channel of the aggregator as both a publish-subscribe and a direct channel and had the issue for both.

When I look at the logs I can see that one of the threads has a preSend to the 'gatherChannel' then `AggregatingMessageHandler` saying it received the message, then another log from `AggregatingMessageHandler` saying `Handling message with correlationKey [f2b16b6a-3605-778f-a628-870ed8ce3f5e]` then a postSend (sent=True) on channel 'gatherChannel'.

I thought that it would not send to the transformResponse channel until both messages that got split out from the splitter got to it. I even added the size() == 2 as the release strategy expression as an extra layer but that doesn't seem to be causing the aggregator to wait either.

I'm a little perplexed why this is happening, it's happening when both the main thread or the spawned thread gets to the aggregator, I'm trying to figure out how to get that aggregator to wait to send to the output channel until BOTH messages that were split from the splitter are received.

Answer (score 0):

According to your current configuration it really does not happen.

Do you really have some evidences that first message in the group is really sent to that `transformResponse` unconditionally?

You probably is a bit confused with those `preSend` and `postSend` since an aggregator is really non-blocking until release. It does accept the message and store it into the `MessageStore` for grouping if release condition is `false`. Just after this it returns immediately to the caller, which is that `gatherChannel` and therefore your see `postSend` on a first message.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense for the pre and post send messages. But I'm getting a response back from the spring integration flow as soon as one of the messages goes through the `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal` method. Even though the aggregator has not released the messages yet, because when I debug through it has not aggregated the messages yet. As soon as I remove the ExecutorChannel and have the newThread channel be a DirectChannel the flow works as expected and does not release to the transformResponse method until the aggregator receives both of the messages.

Comment: Are you sure that you got really a result from that `transformResponse` channel, but not just control because an aggregator has release the calling thread?